# Can $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{m})$ with $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ always be represented using only algebraic functions?

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers, elementary-functions

Can $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{m})$ with $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$  always be represented using only algebraic functions?

In other words can $sin$ of a rational multiple of $\pi$ always be represented using only only algebraic functions (e.g. addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, and roots)?

This question came after failing to find a calculator that could give me the exact value of inputs that I knew had exact values (things like $sin(\frac{\pi}{8})$ and $sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$). As a side question, is there a calculator that can do this? I tried WolframAlpha but it wouldn't always give me an exact value.

Comment: $\sin(n\pi/m)=(t^2-1)/(2it)$, where $t$  is a root of $t^{m}-1=0$ and $i$ a root of $i^2+1=0$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha will give you $\sin\left(\frac \pi8\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}$. It gets more complex for general $m$

Comment: Do you want every "algebraic function" to give you _real_ intermediate results? Or is it acceptable to use complex numbers for intermediate results, as long as the imaginary parts cancel out somehow?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Ideally there would be no complex intermediate results, but is this even possible? If not then complex intermediate results are fine. On that note I found the formula provided by NDB quite good.

Comment: @MorganS42 I think there are some issues with NDB's comment. First of all, $e^{\pi i}=-1.$ Therefore, we need a root of $t^m+1=0$ or $t^{2m}-1=0.$ Furthermore, we cannot take any root. And the last thing: Where does the $n$ come into play? I would expect the correct answer to be something like $(t^n-t^{-n})/(2i),$ where $t$ is the root of $t^m+1=0$ with the smallest possible positive argument. I do not think that there is a solution within the real numbers, but I do not have a proof for that claim.

Comment: Related: [The sine of a single degree](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/awards/college.math.j.47.5.322.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write
$$
\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{m}\right) =
 \frac {e^{n\pi i/m}-e^{-n\pi i/m}}{2i} =
 \frac {t^n-t^{-n}}{2i}
$$
with $t = e^{\pi i/m}.$
$t$ is one of the $m$th roots of $-1.$

To be specific, it is the one with the smallest positive argument among the $m$ roots.

With a lot of hand-waving, you could write
$t = \sqrt[m]{-1}$ to make it look more like an "algebraic function", as long as it is clear from the context which of the roots this is meant to be.

This would result in
$$
\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{m}\right) =
 \frac {\left(\sqrt[m]{-1}\right)^n-\left(\sqrt[m]{-1}\right)^{-n}}{2i}
$$
However, as mentioned above, this requires additional explanations about the usage of the $\sqrt[m]{\;.\;}$ and I would not recommend to write it down in that way.

I do not think that there is a way of expressing $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{m}\right)$ in terms of functions that produce real results, only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer